# Finding First Occurrence Based on Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, syntax

I have a database where every customer have single cust_date, multiple sale date and sale count.  I need pull out data based on the first time that the customer has sale count greater than 0.  Here is a sample data:

```
ID      CUST_DATE      SALE_DATE      SALE_CNT
7      4/20/2009      4/21/2009      0
7      4/20/2009      4/22/2009      0
7      4/20/2009      4/23/2009      5
7      4/20/2009      4/24/2009      3
27      4/21/2009      4/21/2009      4
27      4/21/2009      4/22/2009      0
27      4/21/2009      4/23/2009      2
27      4/21/2009      4/24/2009      0
28      4/20/2009      4/21/2009      1
28      4/20/2009      4/22/2009      0
28      4/20/2009      4/23/2009      0
28      4/20/2009      4/24/2009      0
32      4/21/2009      4/21/2009      0
32      4/21/2009      4/22/2009      0
32      4/21/2009      4/23/2009      0
32      4/21/2009      4/24/2009      0
34      4/21/2009      4/21/2009      0
34      4/21/2009      4/22/2009      0
34      4/21/2009      4/23/2009      0
34      4/21/2009      4/24/2009      0
44      4/20/2009      4/21/2009      0
44      4/20/2009      4/22/2009      3
44      4/20/2009      4/23/2009      0
44      4/20/2009      4/24/2009      0
```

I need my final data to look like the below:

```
ID      CUST_DATE      SALE_DATE      SALE_CNT
7      4/20/2009      4/23/2009      5
27      4/21/2009      4/21/2009      4
28      4/20/2009      4/21/2009      1
44      4/20/2009      4/22/2009      3
```

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way that will work in standard SQL:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.sale_date = (select min(t2.sale_date)
                     from table t2
                     where t2.id = t.id and t2.sale_cnt > 0
                    );
```

Depending on the actual database you are using, there may be other approaches that perform better.  But an index on `table(id, sale_date)` should help the performance regardless of the database.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try.  I am sure this solution will work perfectly in my database